# why shutil.copy and shutil.copy2 create hidden lock files

Tags: python, permissions, copy, shutil, hidden-files

I need copy certain files (that satisfy some condition) from directory in another directory, but I have a problem , that every time I copy the files into the folder with `shutil.copy` or `shutil.copy2` it creates me the `.~lock` files, so I'm not able to perform some other functions on this folder

my function to copy the specific files from one folder to another:

```
def copy_files(path):
    path_input = "%input//" % path
    path_output="%output//" % path
    for i in os.listdir(path_input):
        f=os.path.join(path, i)
        if f.endswith("t.house.csv"):
            shutil.copy(f, path_output) #or shutil.copy2(f, path_output)
```

So my questions: why it happens and how I can avoid creating of `~lock` files? and if I can't avoid,  with which methods I can get rid of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if one of the files that I copy is open, it will create corresponding  `~lock` file in the folder of destination! so, maybe it's not the best and smartest way to fix this bug, but by making sure that there are no open files, I can avoid the creating of `~lock` files